# vb6 win 10 keypress failure

Tags: keypress

I'm constructing a mouse centric form of cut and paste. the user points to an object with the mouse and types a single key to initiate an action. the Object being pointed to is in a picture box which is part of a form and keypreview is set to true for the form. Form_keypress is being used to trap the key being pressed. Pic_mousemove is tracking the mouse position.

but keypress is not reliably trapping the keys. control C works most of the time but not always. control L seems to work most of the time. control S list doesn't work at all. neither does control U.

I've tried moving to regular letters with no success. I've tried using keypress in the picture box; that didn't work either. The behavior is the same in the IDE and from the executable.

what's it take to get a reliable answer?

Comment: Can you show the (relevant) code on how you're intercepting keystrokes?

Comment: Global Anc as String
Global MPos as String
Global Cmd as String

Private Sub Form_Load()
  KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Dim l as String
  If KeyAscii <= 26 Then
    l = KeyAscii + 64
    Select Case l
    Case "C"
      Anc = "Ctrl" + l + MPos
    Case "V"
      Cmd = "Ctrl" + l + MPos
      CopySelected Anc, Cmd
    End Select
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Pic_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  MPos = "(" + Format(X, "##0") + "/" + Format(Y, "##0") + ")"
End Sub